# How to send/receive a date object to be in a different format in JSON and not in timestamp?

Tags: java, json, date, serialization, jackson

I have the following POJO which I use to send out as messages to rabbitmq:

```
public class MyMessage {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Date createdDt;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyMessage(
        @JsonProperty("id") String id,
        @JsonProperty("name") String name,
        @JsonProperty("createdDt") Date createdDt
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.createdDt = createdDt;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that when I send it using `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend()`, the `createdDt` will be in unix timestamp in the JSON message. I need the `createdDt` in the JSON after serialised to be in the format of `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

I don't want to change the `createdDt` property in `MyMessage` class to be a string in that formatted date because I may want to use the POJO else where in the code and having the date as a string is not convenient later. It also doesn't sound "right" to have the date in string just for the purpose of having it in a particular format.

When I'm receiving the message back, I also need to deserialise that string date in the format of `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` back into a `Date` object.

How can I keep the `createdDt` as a `Date` object while sending the date in a different format when serialised and then have the string deserialised back as a date object?

Comment: You can probably avoid the `Date` class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `Instant` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. There's a module to Jackson that will serialize it, https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: FYI, the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard was invented expressly for the data exchange of date-time values as text. These standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque @OleV.V. Thanks, I didn't know that the `java.time` classes are the recommended ones now. I will use the `java.time` classes in this case. Does that mean by registering the `JavaTimeModule`, I would still use the `@JsonFormat` annotation except that Jackson will automatically use the `java.time` classes instead of `Date()` in its date formatting?

Comment: Sorry, @Carven, I don’t know. Try with and without, or read the manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use `java.util.Date` then just add the following annotation onto the `createdDt` field

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
private Date createdDt;
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend not using `java.util.Date` but preferring the Java 8+ Time API. In that case you can import Jackson's built-in support via module `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310` and ...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

...  will, by default, render `LocalDateTime` as an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string.

Ref: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jsr310/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html

Comment: @BasilBorque Do I still have to use `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")` annotation on the `createdDt` class variable after registering the `JavaTimeModule()` to format the date into the pattern I need?

Answer (score 1):

With that specific requirements regarding serialzation/deserialization of the field I would suggest using custom serializer/deserializer.

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<Date> {
 
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        // your implementation
    }
}

public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Item> { 

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

      // your implementation
    }
}
```

Then you can simply mark `createdDt` like this:

```
public class MyMessage {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Date createdDt;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyMessage(
        @JsonProperty("id") String id,
        @JsonProperty("name") String name,
        @JsonProperty("createdDt") @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class) @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class) Date createdDt
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.createdDt = createdDt;
    }
}
```

This way you instruct Jackson to use your specific serializer/deserializer on a specific field.

If you would like to make the configuration to be applied on `ObjectMapper` level you can achieve it with module registration like that:

```
SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule();
myModule.addSerializer(Date.class, new CustomDateSerializer());
myModule.addDeserializer(Date.class, new CustomDateDeserializer());

objectMapper.registerModule(myModule);
```